# iPhone storage & retrieval in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I have developed a PhoneGap app for the Android that plays mp3s.  I have succefully installed the app on the iPhone with Xcode, but there are two things I don't know how to do:

1. How do I transfer media files to the iPhone sdcard? (with the Android I use 'adb push')
2. What directory will media.play() play from in iOS as a default? (with the Android it is the sd card root at /sdcard/)

Thanks.

Comment: iPhone SD card?  Tell me more of this SD card slot of which you speak...  LOL.  IOS doesn't support external drives, do you mean writing to the disk?

Comment: This is already such an embarrassingly newb question as it is, it pains me to ask it, it's just that the PhoneGap documentation is abysmal and I've never developed for mobile devices before. Yes, the non-removable iPhone storage.  :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used phoneGapp but i understand is a html+js wrapper, in a native app, so what you have for the native app might be valid?

so if you have Xcode, just drag and drop your mp3 file to the folder on the left "project navigator", you can use any folder, but for organisation, use the resources, if you want you can create a subfolder.

the data gets stored in the sandbox file system for your app bundle.

also you can save data on the "Documents" folder of your app, but this is done on runtime, not an "asset".

so the directory of your app bundle files is accessible with NSBundle:

```
   NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
     NSLog(@"the bundle Root: %@",bundleRoot);

     NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];

     NSLog(@"content of bundle ::%@", dirContents);
```

that code will show you the

```
the bundle Root: /Users/tkt/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/2BD76563-7D7C-4E30-9F37-6B099CBB2B47/jozziApp.app
```

for the simulator, and its equivalent in the device.

and the content of the bundle:

```
content of bundle ::(
    "aboutIcon.png",
    "bio.html",
    "bio_bgnd.png",***)
```

so this is not for phoneGap, but tells you how to import, and where the files at!

good luck

Comment: I put the files in www/assets.  That did the trick.  Apple made this much more intuitive in iOS than Android.  Thanks!